# Bring view to front on MaterialCardView and ConstraintLayout with elevation

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

within my layout which contains a `MaterialCardView` i want to add `app:cardElevation="10dp"`.

[image]

But when I apply the `cardElevation` my button gets messed up.

[image]

I tried many suggestions from other questions like adding a huge amount of elevation to the button or changing the Z order but it doesn't work.

```
    ViewCompat.setElevation(button, 1000.0f)
    ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(button, 1000.0f)
    button.bringToFront()
    login_card.invalidate()
```

Any ideas?

[Complete Layout Xml](https://gist.github.com/chrjsorg/67131e72bddb0056618620ae23c3e095)
Layout XML (shortened):

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/login_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="10dp i'm breaking the layout-----------"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        ...
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        ...
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button_login"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/login_button_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="1000dp"
    android:text="@string/login_button_login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />
```

Comment: What is the rot element at your xml?

Comment: The root view is also a `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Can you post your complete xml so that i can try in my system

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrjsorg/67131e72bddb0056618620ae23c3e095 This should be fine.

Comment: cardElevation for a materialCardView means bringing a view on top so that it highlights the surface. More info: https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#depicting-elevation

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use `app:cardElevation="0dp"` so other views could be on top of it. I used the `panel` as a background for other buttons and texts.

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/autogrow"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"

        />
```

Answer (score 0):

This hacky way worked for me.
Just wrap your `MaterialCardView` with `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/login_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardElevation="10dp i'm breaking the layout-----------"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                ...
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                ...
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</FrameLayout>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button_login"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/login_button_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="1000dp"
    android:text="@string/login_button_login"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_card"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />
```